# Thousands Separator for String Suffixed by Letters

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is there any simple solution to adding a thousands separator to a string that is suffixed with letters?

for example, I get data in as such:

```
123456 km
```

And I would like to turn that into:

```
123,456 km
```

is there a simple solution short of stripping the data of the suffix, doing `String.Format("0:n0")`, then re-adding the suffix back in?

Edit: Suffix not Prefix.

Comment: Isn't `km` a suffix here?

Comment: -sigh- yes my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *regular expressions*: just extract and replace all long enough values, e.g.

```
  string source = "the distance was 123456.47 km and the speed was 1234 m/s";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    source,
    @"([0-9]{4,})((\s*[a-zA-Z]+)|(\.))",
    match => double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value).ToString("#,##0") +
             match.Groups[2].Value);

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome

```
  the distance was 123,456.47 km and the speed was 1,234 m/s
```

Comment: Although your answer is much more powerful than what i need. my data is solely limited to a number suffixed by a distance unit such as "km", "mi", etc. but yeah this seems like it could work.

Comment: @Cristian C.: you can analyze suffix as well: it's `match.Groups[3].Value` e.g. `match => Suffixes.Contains(match.Groups[3].Value.Trim()) ? double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value).ToString("#,##0") +       match.Groups[2].Value : match.Value`

Answer (score 2):

Use this as Match Evaluator:

```
 static string Seprator(Match m)
 {
     return int.Parse(m.ToString()).ToString("N0");
 }
```

Then this will give you the resulkt you want:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(a, "[0-9]+",new MatchEvaluator(Seprator));
```

Here is The [**Live Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2DikGN)

Comment: Eerie *counter example*: `"fail ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ km"` *persian digits* will pass `"\\d+"` pattern, but fail `int.Parse`. Sure, I doubt if this and alike input can appear in the context, but there's a simple remedy: either change `\\d` to `[0-9]` or add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

Comment: Well actually I was suggesting a solution and didn't pay much attention to Regex Pattern itself, I thought having the solution user can change it as he likes. and thanks for mentioning, I change the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string number = String.Format("0:n0", double.Parse(yournumber.Split(" ").GetValue(0).ToString())) + yournumber.Split(" ").GetValue(1).ToString();
```

Comment: yeah, i was thinking i would probably have to go down this route. Thank you though.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you need to have that one space between the digits and the letters.

Comment: the thing is, this solution works (for me specifically), because I know that I'll have that space every time.

Comment: You can also get the index of the first letter by using LINQ, and then use it to split the suffex.